# How to compare two S3 objects by content "server-side"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Let's say I have any 2 objects stored in Amazon S3 in the same bucket (as the input of the task). I need to compare them by content. Not only that their length and checksum is the same but literally that the objects are identical byte after byte. The only way how I can do it now is reading the objects' data into my app on EC2 and comparing them. That, however, is not very time efficient and as well costs money for the data transfer.
Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Could I do it somehow using a server-side code on S3 (some sort of lambda or similar) that would do that comparison without downloading the data to the EC2?

Comment: why don't you use SHA1 to compare whether the files are equal or not? that's enough to safely assume they are the same file.

Comment: There are some issues with this question.  If the bucket is in the same region as EC2 and an S3 VPC endpoint is used, there should not be a data transfer charge.  Another issue is that Lambda functions -- technically -- still run on EC2 hardware so while it's simpler from a scaling/manageability standpoint, it is fundamentally the same thing as using EC2 in the very limited context of this question.  S3 itself offers no server-side execution.

Comment: @ThalesMinussi is correct, though there are limited, known SHA-1 collisions.  SHA-256 + length should be sufficient for any case, but if the motivation is strictly limited to checking for *accidental* corruption of two files believed to be identical (e.g. you copied one to the other, yourself, and want to validate that the copy has no bit flips or other transposition/corruption) then MD5 + length should be sufficient for that very limited purpose.

Comment: @Michael I think every hashing solution will have a chance of collisions. I need to be practically 100% sure that the content is the same. This is not to exclude accidental corruption. I want to store the content of my documents only once in S3 if they are the same. For that I need to detect that I already have that same document stored. I can recognize it using the hash but then I need to verify that the content really is the same. The chance is probably small but it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S3 is made for storage purpose, with some automatic task around replication and versioning. It doesn't do processing of your data. S3 itself don't compare in terms of objects, what it sees is only the bytes.

Even if you read the data in lambda, it will also cost the data transfer charges.

It depends on what you think of efficient program? cost efficient or time efficient (without synchronously blocking your app flow.

1. Your upload to s3 bucket can send an event notification to aws lambda, which will then read your objects and compare them, and then may store results (dynamo db or somewhere else).
   If you don't need real time compare, then you may take a look at scheduled events in aws lambda, which runs after specific interval.

Comment: You don't pay for data transferred from an Amazon S3 bucket to an AWS service, such as Lambda, in the same AWS Region as the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

There is the MD5 hash as part of the ETag for S3 objects too, which might or might not be enough in this example. This also forms part of the S3 Inventory service which can be used although this would incur extra costs. Obviously the MD5 algorithm isn't as robust as previous comments made above.